# Projection Operator in qiskit.opflow

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am looking for a way to implement a projection operator like $\mid +\rangle\langle+\mid$ in qiskits opflow module. I tried `Plus @ ~Plus` but this gives me an error message. There must be a direct implementation of projection operators right? I can't use the operators in `qiskit.quantum_info` for what I want to do, except if there is a way to convert those operators to the ones in opflow.

Edit:
The error message I get from `(Plus)@(~Plus)` is `ValueError: Composition with a Statefunctions in the first operand is not defined.`

The reason I think I can't use `qiskit.quantum_info`'s opearotors it that I want to compute the spectrum using `qiskit.algorithms.NumPyEigensolver` and this seems to me to not work with a `quantum_info` operator:

```
>>>plus = Statevector([1/np.sqrt(2),1/np.sqrt(2)]).to_operator()
>>>plus
Operator([[0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j],
          [0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j]],
         input_dims=(2,), output_dims=(2,))

>>>solver = NumPyEigensolver()
>>>spectrum = solver.compute_eigenvalues(plus)
AttributeError: 'Operator' object has no attribute 'to_spmatrix'
```

I am generally confused about the connection and difference between `qiskit.quantum_info` and `qiskit.opflow` because they seem to me to have a large overlap. Is one of those an older module and should not be used anymore? Is there a general way to convert objects like operators from one to the other?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! There is some context information missing from your question that might help folks answer it: what error message you see and why you think that you can't use operators in `qiskit.quantum_info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a `qiskit.quantum_info` operator to a `qiskit.opflow` operator easily by passing it as a parameter to [`PrimitiveOp`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.PrimitiveOp.html) constructor:

```
from qiskit.opflow import PrimitiveOp

# |+>
sv = Statevector.from_label('+')

# |+><+|
proj = sv.to_operator()

# Convert to opflow operator:
op = PrimitiveOp(proj)
```